# Weird issue with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to pull out `tableHeaderView` of `UITableView`.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *floatingHeaderView;

- (void)setUp
{
    UIView *tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    UIView *dummyTableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tableHeaderView.frame];

    CGRect frame = tableHeaderView.frame;
    frame.size.width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;
    tableHeaderView.frame = frame;

    [tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tableView addSubview:tableHeaderView];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = dummyTableHeaderView;
    self.floatingHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
}
```

First, I made a strong reference to `self.tableView.tableHeaderView`. Then, I removed `tableHeaderView` from superview and added it to `self.tableView`. Lastly, I made a weak reference to `tableViewHeader` because I thought that `tableViewHeader` has a strong reference with `self.tableView.subviews`. But during runtime, `self.floatingHeaderView` points to `nil`.

How can I resolve this weird issue?

Comment: when do you call setUp?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure tableView maintains a strong reference to it's subviews, not the other way around. I'm guessing when you call [tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview]; it makes a delegate call to it's superview telling it it needs to be removed. This would still be a weak reference.

So you need to make floatingHeaderView a strong pointer.